# Need a protocol for various NSObject subtypes, can't return 'NSObject' for 'Self'

Tags: swift, class, static, protocols

I'm trying to make a protocol so that I can unwrap **NSObject** values and handle them appropriately with a snazzy helper class.

There are basically two cases:

1. The type I'm expecting has special handling (NSValue->CGRect, NSNumber->Int)
2. The type I'm expecting is already an **NSObject** subclass

The following code does not compile no matter how many casts I attempt.

"Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSObject?' to expected return type 'Self?'"

```
public protocol NSObjectWrappable {
    static func fromNSObject(value : NSObject?) -> Self?
}

extension NSObject : NSObjectWrappable {
    public static func fromNSObject(value: NSObject?) -> Self? {
        return value
    }
}
```

To give a bigger picture, I've also got essentially this:

```
extension CGRect : NSObjectWrappable {
    public static func fromNSObject(value : NSObject?) -> Self? {
        /// yatta yatta NSValue.CGRectValue()
    }
}
```

The idea being that I might be able to use some generic helper methods against Cocoa APIs that use dictionaries.

Given that I apparently can't go about it the way I was wanting to, what is a way that will work with minimal code duplication?  Ideally I'd be able to specialize generics, but I don't think that's possible.

(This is Swift 2.0 so the syntax might be slightly different.)

Comment: May I ask why you claim to need a generic for this? Why not just receive the value and look at its type and act accordingly?

Comment: I want to see how slick I can get a type safety KVO API.  It's a good Swift learning project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest code that I can come up with:

```
import Foundation

// The protocol defines no method
public protocol NSObjectWrappable {}

// The 'default' implementation
func fromNSObject<T : NSObject, U : NSObjectWrappable>(value : T?) -> U? {
    return value as? U
}


// Usage
extension NSNumber : NSObjectWrappable {}
extension NSDictionary : NSObjectWrappable {}

let aNumber = NSNumber(integer: 42) as NSObject
let unwrappedNumber : NSNumber? = fromNSObject(aNumber)

let aDict = NSDictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("name", "John Smith"), ("age", "42")) as NSObject
let unwrappedDict : NSDictionary? = fromNSObject(aDict)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how would you expand primitives to this?  What I was striving for was getting structs type-safely out of NSValue, primitive numbers out of NSNumber, and just returning the input for anything without special handling.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was slight code duplication.  So, I'll leave my question open in case there is a better Swift way of doing this with generics.  I ended up making 3 classes, and 3 helper methods, and due to type inference it's not a huge deal.

```
public extension NSObject {
    func addObserver<Type : NSValueWrappable>(keyPath: String, handler: (kind : NSKeyValueChange, oldValue: Type?, newValue: Type?) -> Void) -> protocol<KeyValueObserver> {
        let opts : NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New]
        let observer = KeyValueStructObserver<Type>(object: self, keyPath: keyPath, options: opts)
        observer.changeHandler = handler
        observer.startObserving()
        return observer
    }

    func addObserver<Type : NSNumberWrappable>(keyPath: String, handler: (kind : NSKeyValueChange, oldValue: Type?, newValue: Type?) -> Void) -> protocol<KeyValueObserver> {
        let opts : NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New]
        let observer = KeyValueNumberObserver<Type>(object: self, keyPath: keyPath, options: opts)
        observer.changeHandler = handler
        observer.startObserving()
        return observer
    }

    func addObserver<Type : NSObject>(keyPath: String, handler: (kind : NSKeyValueChange, oldValue: Type?, newValue: Type?) -> Void) -> protocol<KeyValueObserver> {
        let opts : NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New]
        let observer = KeyValueObjectObserver<Type>(object: self, keyPath: keyPath, options: opts)
        observer.changeHandler = handler
        observer.startObserving()
        return observer
    }
}
```

Example usage for clarity:

```
_tabBar.addObserver("frame"){(_, oldValue: CGRect?, newValue: CGRect?) in
            let rect = newValue!
            print(rect)
        }
```